# how to fix missing transport error in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Whenever I try to Install any plugin or theme WordPress gives an error as:

> Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found

Please Help!

Comment: Explain your environment and tell what you already tried to do. Do some research first, a simple google query for "No working transports found" returns relevant matches.

Answer (score 2):

This error message occurs when there are **missing extensions** on a development server, so the WordPress is unable to make external HTTP requests.

The solution is pretty simple. The missing extensions that make those HTTP requests possible are already installed with Wamp Server, By default,they are just disabled. To enable them, we need to edit the php.ini configuration file.

Editing **php.ini** file

The php.ini file contains a list of many extensions with some of them disabled by default. The only one I had to enable was the openssl extension.

**Here are the steps to enable that extension:**

1. Start Wamp Server.
2. click on Wamp Server Icon and move to PHP->php.ini option.
3. double click on php.ini. so, it will open php.ini file in your default Text Editor.
4. search for **php_openssl.dll** in php.ini file. ->You Will see that the extension is commented out: ;extension=php_openssl.dll
5. Uncomment that line by removing semicolon(;)
6. Save the changes.
7. Restart Wamp Server.